# SQL duration between two dates in different rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I would really appreciate some assistance if somebody could help me construct a MSSQL Server 2000 query that would return the duration between  a customer's A entry and their B entry.

Not all customers are expected to have a B record and so no results would be returned.

*Customers Audit*

```
+---+---------------+---+----------------------+
| 1 | Peter Griffin | A | 2013-01-01  15:00:00 |
| 2 | Martin Biggs  | A | 2013-01-02  15:00:00 |
| 3 | Peter Griffin | C | 2013-01-05  09:00:00 |
| 4 | Super Mario   | A | 2013-01-01  15:00:00 |
| 5 | Martin Biggs  | B | 2013-01-03  18:00:00 |
+---+---------------+---+----------------------+
```

I'm hoping for results similar to:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| Martin Biggs | 1 day, 3 hours |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the below (don't know your schema, so you'll need to change names of objects) should suffice.

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, CA.TheDate, CB.TheDate)) AS HoursBetween
FROM dbo.Customers CA
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers CB
ON CB.Name = CA.Name
AND CB.Code = 'B'
WHERE CA.Code = 'A'
```

Comment: how can we determine that `CB.TheDate` will be greater than the other date? Otherwise `DATEDIFF` may results in negative hours? :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - right, we can't infer this from the specification and single example, if the dates may be 'the other way around' it's easily addressed by `ABS(...)` (now added to the answer).

Comment: This was enough information for me to make use of - also I've learnt the ABS function :)

Comment: :) I was referring to `ABS()` and perhaps this would give that [`Days, Hours` as well](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de5cf/15)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.CUSTOMER, DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.ENTRY_DATE, B.ENTRY_DATE) DURATION
FROM CUSTOMERSAUDIT A, CUSTOMERSAUDIT B
WHERE B.CUSTOMER = A.CUSTOMER AND B.ENTRY_DATE > A.ENTRY_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle query but all features available in MS Server as far as I know. I'm sure I do not have to tell you how to concatenate the output to get desired result. All values in output will be in separate columns - days, hours, etc... And it is not always easy to format the output here:

```
SELECT id, name, grade
     , NVL(EXTRACT(DAY    FROM day_time_diff), 0) days
     , NVL(EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM day_time_diff), 0) hours
     , NVL(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM day_time_diff), 0) minutes
     , NVL(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM day_time_diff), 0) seconds
  FROM
  (
   SELECT id, name, grade
       , (begin_date-end_date) day_time_diff
     FROM
     (
      SELECT id, name, grade
           , CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP)  begin_date
           , CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP)    end_date
        FROM
         (
          SELECT id, name, grade, start_date
               , LAG(start_date, 1, to_date(null)) OVER (ORDER BY id)  end_date 
            FROM stack_test
         )
     )
   )
   /

Output:

ID  NAME           GRADE    DAYS    HOURS   MINUTES SECONDS
------------------------------------------------------------
 1  Peter Griffin   A       0        0      0       0
 2  Martin Biggs    A       1        1      0       0
 3  Peter Griffin   C       2        17     0       0
 4  Super Mario     A      -3       -18     0       0
 5  Martin Biggs    A       2        3      0       0
```

The table structure/columns I used - it would be great if you took care of this and data in advance:

```
CREATE TABLE stack_test
 (
  id        NUMBER
 ,name      VARCHAR2(50) 
 ,grade     VARCHAR2(3)
 ,start_date DATE
)
/
```